# f is a function from R to R and there exists a continuous function g from R to R such that f=g a.e., then does it imply that f is continuous a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

I think it does imply but I am not sure. My argument was f=g on a finite set, so barring those finite points we can say that f is continuous, so f is continuous on all but countably many points which imply f is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: a.e. does not mean that the exception set is finite, but has measure $0$. So $f=g$ except on a finite set is not true.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational and $0$ for $x$ irrational Let $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. This is a counter-example.

Comment: But isn't f continuous a.e. as Q is a measure zero set in R .?

Comment: @RajatMishra No. Continuous almost everywhere means there exists a set $E$ of measure $0$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x$ whenever $x \notin E$. The function I have defined is not continuous at any point.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks..